# Retorno do select traz valor anterior - jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tenho uma tabela *#tabela* e gostaria que a cada vez que eu faço um filtro pelo select ele some a quantidade que está na coluna 6 *eq(5)*. Com o código abaixo ele está executando, porém ele exibe o valor anterior que eu seleciono. Por exemplo, está exibindo 3 linhas com 5, 5 e 5 em cada uma delas. Quando eu troco o *option* do *select* para qualquer outra opção, aí que ele vai me mostrar a soma, 25 no console.

```
 $('select').on('change', function() {
    var qtd = 0
    $("#tabela tbody tr:not(.filtered)").each(function(){
        qtd += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(5).html())
    });
    console.log(qtd);
});
```

Qual evento eu poderia utilizar para que ele calculasse quando troco a seleção do `<select>`. Eu havia pensado no óbvio, o *change*.

Sou iniciante eh jQuery, então se o código puder ser escrito de uma melhor forma, fique a vontade para sugerir.

Obrigado.

Comment: O valor do select na verdade não me importa. Eu utilizo ele apenas para filtro, se seleciono opção Teste, ele filtra para 3 linhas na tabela, por exemplo. Eu então conto as linhas filtradas, pela classe .filtered. E assim vou somando a cara linha para saber o total que tenho.

Comment: Se ao mudar o select é efetuado o fltro e ao mesmo tempo chamado o "onchange", vai dar problema porque as duas coisas não vão ser processadas em sincronia.

Comment: É o próprio jQuery que faz, um script que uso a classe tablesorter. Veja nesta imagem https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/img-jpg--188. Eu quero somar o 50 + 1 quando eu troco o filtro de qualquer select (seta preta). Ele soma, mas ele vai mostrar o 51 só depois q eu trocar o filtro de novo.

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer que isso funcione, é possível?

Comment: O plugin é este http://tablesorter.com/docs/?

Comment: Ainda continua calculando depois que troco de option. =/

Comment: Isso, estão assim os ths: <th data-placeholder='Filtro' class='filter-select filter-exact'><b>Nº Licença</b></th> e o table: <table id='tabela' class='tablesorter'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O plugin [Tablesorter Filter Widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) possui um *trigger* que é disparado após o fim do filtro.

Então coloque os cálculos dentro do *trigger*:

```
$("#tabela").on("filterEnd",function() {
   var qtd = 0
   $("#tabela tbody tr:not(.filtered)").each(function(){
      qtd += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(5).html())
   });
   console.log(qtd);
});
```

Coloque após a inicialização do plugin:

```
$("#tabela").tablesorter();
```

Comment: <script src="jquery.tablesorter-customized.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>            
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

Estes são os scripts que eu chamo na página menu.php e nesta página que tenho o código eu faço um include neste menu.php. Mas em ambas eu não tenho esse $("#tabela").tablesorter();

Comment: @netovgs Seria bom disponibilizar um exemplo de HTML da tabela incluindo os selects pra gente dá uma olhada.

Comment: Coloquei este seu código no fim do meu, e não retornou nada.

Comment: @netovgs Tinha que ver onde é que o plugin é inciado. Não precisa ser exatamente `$("#tabela").tablesorter();`, mas alguma coisa parecida

Comment: @netovgs Troca o "change" por "blur" para ver se funciona. O "blur" vc deve alterar o select e tirar o foco dele.

Comment: Fiz o que vc disse, e já apareceu uma luz rs...ele calcula agora conforme eu tiro o foco do Select. Só que aí tento colocar isso: $("#tabela thead tr td input[type=search]").eq(0).focus() para jogar o foco em um input search do lado e assim ele calcular. Mas quem diz que isso funciona?! Se eu uso somente este código ele seleciona exatamente o objeto, agora se eu coloco o .focus, ele não coloca o foco no input. O código está correto ou tem outra forma para fazer? Seila, um lostfocus depois do blur...está por pouco rsrs. Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72426/discussion-between-netovgs-and-dvd).

Comment: Alguém com alguma sugestão para ajudar? Talvez como dar um tab após o change do select e assim executar o blur...nem sei se seria o caminho correto. =/

Comment: Agora sim!!! Tem o mesmo resultado que o meu, mas sem dúvidas o seu é muito mais prático e limpo. Muito obrigado @dvd.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var qtd = 0;

    $('select').on('blur', function(e) {  
        qtd = 0;
        $("#tabela tbody tr:not(.filtered)").each(function() {
            qtd += parseInt($(this).find('td').eq(5).html());  
        });
    });

    $('select').on('change', function() {       
        setTimeout (function() { 
            $("#tabela thead tr td input[type=search]").eq(0).focus(); 
            $('#total').html(qtd);
        }, 300);
    }); 
});
```

Não sei se esta é a melhor forma para se fazer isso, se está seguindo as boas práticas. Caso alguém tenha uma forma mais correta, por favor compartilhe.

@dvd obrigado por sua ajuda.

Abraços.